# Does the MultiBit linux jar file run in windows?

Tags: linux, multibit, windows, java

A windows system has a standalone java and is not recognized by the installer. A jar file can be run on the command line. Is the MultiBit linux jar and the windows installed one the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux *installer* is slightly different to the windows installer in that there are different scripts to get the host machine to recognise the bitcoin URIs.

What ARE very similar is the multibit-exe.jar (used on Linux and Mac) and the multibit.exe (used in Windows). The exe is basically a wrapped jar file.

On any operating system you can run MultiBit jar file by running:

cd 'the MultiBit installation directory'

'path to java'/java -jar multibit-exe.jar

Make sure you cd to the install directory first as it uses that to pick up some files.

Comment: Great. I thought a jar is a jar anywhere and wanted to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: Are these scripts (reg files?) necessary for the windows client to function properly? The reason for the question in the first place is that the installer will not allow to install if it does not find java. As an alternative, have a no-install zip package or have the installer option to install anyway. Of course 99.999999999999% of normal users would never need these options. Maybe the only one right here. Another option is to have the scripts you mentioned as a download on your site. If the scripts are not needed then disregard this comment. lol

Comment: The scripts are to register MultiBit to handle bitcoin URI links when you click them in a browser.